# Selecting from label before copying! -Swift project

Tags: xcode, swift, select, copy, uilabel

I followed this tutorial to make the label able to copy: 
http://stephenradford.me/make-uilabel-copyable/

It worked as here:
[image]

Is there any way, to add a selection! So the user can select exactly what he/she wants to copy from the label?

Comment: That's strange! I have just recreated what you have done. This is what you want to do, right? https://www.dropbox.com/s/u9r2vo8l068iurz/image.jpeg?dl=0

Comment: Yes, but I just want select, copy and define!

Comment: How can I do that?